# Zip folders in folders in Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, zip, directory

I don't know how to title this topic, but all I need to know if there is a way how to zip all folders inside one other folder.

This is my path:

```
/foldername/01/foldername2
/foldername/02/foldername2
```

I was hoping if there was something like this:

```
zip -r /tmp/my.zip /foldername/*/foldername2
```

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get a list of nested `foldername2` with `find` like this:

```
$ find /foldername -type d -a -name foldername2
```

and pass this list to `zip`:

```
$ zip -r /tmp/my.zip $(find /foldername -type d -a -name flodername2)
```